# xcode9 not able to generate .xcworkspace file with cocoa pods

Tags: ios, cocoapods, xcode9

With `xcode9` i am trying the install some libraries with cocoapods, but after running `pod install` **.xcworkspace** file is not generating, I have also tried to update cocoapods, but after updating the pods also **.xcworkspace** file is not generating.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Works fine for me using `Xcode 9` if I follow these steps with `Cocoapods` version `1.1+`

- Create new `Xcode` project (let's say with the name of `Cocoapods`).
- Follow the `Xcode` project location and `pod init` it will create `Podfile`
- Open the `Podfile` using `open -e Podfile` add Libraries names and `pod install`

[image]

But in your case `Podfile.lock` is missing. I guess you should run `pod deintegrate` and `pod install` once again if still, you face the issue then you need to change the `Cocoapods` version.

Comment: issue is with the version of cocoapods, now working fine